# Kubernetes worker nodes cpu and memory requests remains zero always

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes

Hi i am new to kubernetes.

1) Could not able to scaled container/pods in worker nodes. and its memory usage always remain zero. any reason ?

2) Whenever i scaled pods/container its always create in master node.

3) Is there any way to limit pod on specific nodes ?

4) How pods divide when i scaled ?

any help appropriated.

**kubectl version**

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13", GitVersion:"v1.13.3", GitCommit:"721bfa751924da8d1680787490c54b9179b1fed0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-02-01T20:08:12Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13", GitVersion:"v1.13.3", GitCommit:"721bfa751924da8d1680787490c54b9179b1fed0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-02-01T20:00:57Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

**kubectl describe nodes**

```
Name:               worker-node
Roles:              worker
Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=worker-node
                    node-role.kubernetes.io/worker=worker
Annotations:        kubeadm.alpha.kubernetes.io/cri-socket: /var/run/dockershim.sock
                    node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: 0
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: true
CreationTimestamp:  Tue, 19 Feb 2019 15:03:33 +0530
Taints:             node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure:NoSchedule
Unschedulable:      false
Conditions:
  Type             Status    LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----             ------    -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  MemoryPressure   False     Tue, 19 Feb 2019 18:57:22 +0530   Tue, 19 Feb 2019 15:26:13 +0530   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure     True      Tue, 19 Feb 2019 18:57:22 +0530   Tue, 19 Feb 2019 15:26:23 +0530   KubeletHasDiskPressure       kubelet has disk pressure
  PIDPressure      False     Tue, 19 Feb 2019 18:57:22 +0530   Tue, 19 Feb 2019 15:26:13 +0530   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
  Ready            True      Tue, 19 Feb 2019 18:57:22 +0530   Tue, 19 Feb 2019 15:26:13 +0530   KubeletReady                 kubelet is posting ready status. AppArmor enabled
  OutOfDisk        Unknown   Tue, 19 Feb 2019 15:03:33 +0530   Tue, 19 Feb 2019 15:25:47 +0530   NodeStatusNeverUpdated       Kubelet never posted node status.
Addresses:
  InternalIP:  192.168.1.10
  Hostname:    worker-node
Capacity:
 cpu:                4
 ephemeral-storage:  229335396Ki
 hugepages-2Mi:      0
 memory:             16101704Ki
 pods:               110
Allocatable:
 cpu:                4
 ephemeral-storage:  211355500604
 hugepages-2Mi:      0
 memory:             15999304Ki
 pods:               110
System Info:
 Machine ID:                 1082300ebda9485cae458a9761313649
 System UUID:                E4DAAC81-5262-11CB-96ED-94898013122F
 Boot ID:                    ffd5ce4b-437f-4497-9337-e72c06f88429
 Kernel Version:             4.15.0-45-generic
 OS Image:                   Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
 Operating System:           linux
 Architecture:               amd64
 Container Runtime Version:  docker://18.6.1
 Kubelet Version:            v1.13.3
 Kube-Proxy Version:         v1.13.3
PodCIDR:                     192.168.1.0/24
Non-terminated Pods:         (0 in total)
  Namespace                  Name    CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  AGE
  ---------                  ----    ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource           Requests  Limits
  --------           --------  ------
  cpu                0 (0%)    0 (0%)
  memory             0 (0%)    0 (0%)
  ephemeral-storage  0 (0%)    0 (0%)
Events:
  Type     Reason                Age                     From                       Message
  ----     ------                ----                    ----                       -------
  Normal   Starting              55m                     kube-proxy, worker-node  Starting kube-proxy.
  Normal   Starting              55m                     kube-proxy, worker-node  Starting kube-proxy.
  Normal   Starting              33m                     kube-proxy, worker-node  Starting kube-proxy.
  Normal   Starting              11m                     kube-proxy, worker-node  Starting kube-proxy.
  Warning  EvictionThresholdMet  65s (x1139 over 3h31m)  kubelet, worker-node     Attempting to reclaim ephemeral-storage
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is very strange, by default kubernetes has the label to exclude the master from pod execution.

```
kubectl get nodes --show-labels
```

Now check for the label

```
node-role.kubernetes.io/master=true:NoSchedule
```

If your master doesn't has this label, you can retain the master with:

```
kubectl taint nodes $HOSTNAME node-role.kubernetes.io/master=true:NoSchedule
```

Comment: The output of  kubectl get nodes --show-labels ----------------------------- kmaster         Ready    master   6h      v1.13.3   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,kubernetes.io/hostname=kmaster,node-role.kubernetes.io/master=
worker-node   Ready    worker   4h34m   v1.13.3   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,kubernetes.io/hostname=worker-node,node-role.kubernetes.io/worker=worker

Comment: The output of ---- kubectl taint nodes serverhostname node-role.kubernetes.io/master=true:NoSchedule -----------------------  Error from server (NotFound): nodes "serverhostname" not found

Comment: sorry, but in serverhostname you need to use the hostname of your master server :)

Comment: sorry to ask silly question,  how i can use hostname ?

Comment: the node name the you see in kubectl get nodes

Comment: Ohhh got it... but that does not solved issue right ? 
the output is node/kmaster tainted

Comment: Now if your master is tainted you need to check if you have application pod running, anyway, if your cluster is new cluster is normal, that you have memory usage on the master, because on the master there is  the system pods, you can verify that with kubectl get pods -n kube-system -o wide

Comment: Application pods running but that is in master always? worker remain idel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188683/discussion-between-c4f4t0r-and-bhargav-patel).